# How can I count the outputs of a while loop in python?

Tags: python, while-loop, count, output

I would like to be able to insert a line of code that counts the number of times the output is "watch".

[image: This is the picture of my current code]

Comment: Please post code as text. It makes it easier for people to help you by being able to copy-paste it. Also it seems you are aware of variables. Did you know you can do something like `x = x + 1`? If you start with `x = 0` you can count stuff

Comment: add a count variable and increment whenever the condition is watch and finally print it

Comment: You can calculate it arithmetically, there's no need to count.

Comment: A simple counter maybe? Something like `i += 1`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this one:

```
counter = 0
while Amzn > 1000:
    counter+=1
    print("Watch")
    Amzn = Amzn - (Amzn*.0103)
else:
    print("buy")
print(counter)
```

Comment: That worked! Thank you

Answer (score 0):

```py
i = 0

[...stuff...]

i += 1
print(f"Watch {i}")
```

Comment: It would be clearer for the OP (who seems to be a beginner) to show the actual `while` loop than `...stuff...`.